# How to do trial and error for my model

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I have the following Model:

$(A-BX)^TS^{-1}(A-BX)$ which I would like to tune only $S$ and $B$  to make it equal to $mI$ where $A\in \mathcal{M}_{n,m}$, $B\in \mathcal{M}_{n,n}$, $X\in \mathcal{M}_{n,m}$ and $S\in \mathbb{S}_{n,n}$ which is spd.

So how can I tune my matrices $B$ and $S$ to make the above product equal to $mI$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably $n\ge m$ and the matrices are real. Pick any $B$ such that $A-BX$ has full rank. Perform a singular value decomposition $A-BX=U\begin{pmatrix}\Sigma\\0\end{pmatrix}V^T$. Let
$$
S=U\begin{pmatrix}\frac1m\Sigma^2\\&I_{n-m}\end{pmatrix}U^T
$$
and we are done.

Comment: could you please help me to solve the following problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360831/how-can-i-generate-a-model-where-the-likelihood-is-proportional-to-identity-matr