# special matrix in terms of its covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution, mathematical-modeling, correlation, noise

How can we find a matrix $S\in \mathcal{M}_{n,n}$ and $Z\in \mathcal{M}_{n,m}$ whose $n$ entries of the $i^{th}$ column $Z_i$ are correlated $Z_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,S)$ where $S \in \mathcal{M}_{n,n}$ is the covariance matrix of the $n$ entries such that:

$E(Z^T S^{-1}Z)=mI$

Comment: @MichaelGrant My main question is how to generate a model where the likelihood is equal to $mI$. That is, if our model is defined as $Y=BX + E$ then we have $(Y-BX)^TS^{-1}(Y-BX)=mI$. Can we generate such a model?

Comment: you're right, I just corrected my question above.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep pestering here :P But is $S$ already known? If not, why not just choose $S=I$?

Comment: @MichaelGrant $S$ is known here and it could be any covariance matrix. In my case I'm choosing it as $s_{i,j}=\rho^{|i-j|}$ where $\rho$ is a fixed correlation coefficient.

Comment: OK, then again, I recommend editing your question to make this clear. The text as I read it says that $S$ is to be found. It seems tedious but remember the quality of the question matters here! Someone else might be interested in it.

Comment: So what else is required here? What is missing from the answer below?

Comment: Actually I didn't get really the point why we should use the expected value because what I'm considering is one realization of a randomly distributed matrix where the matrix is not anymore random. So we can get rid of the Expected value.

Comment: If you get rid of the expected value then $Z$ cannot be constructed randomly. Yes, there are an infinite number of solutions to $Z^TS^{-1}Z=mI$, but they don't have the random character you've described. The method I offer below is a way to generate a single random instance of $Z$ from a distribution matching the above statistics.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that $S$ is already known; otherwise, you can just choose $S=I$ and you're done--except for an $m/n$ issue here that I do not think can be avoided; you'll see below.

Let $\tilde{Z}$ be an $n\times m$ random matrix with elements independently drawn from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
$$\textbf{E}(\tilde{Z}_i\tilde{Z}_j^T) = \begin{cases} I & i=j \\ 0_{n,n} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \tilde{Z}_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I).$$
$$\textbf{E}(\tilde{Z}_i^T\tilde{Z}_j) = \begin{cases} n & i=j \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \textbf{E}(\tilde{Z}^T\tilde{Z}) = nI.$$
Incidentally, the second line follows trivially the first, since $\tilde{Z}_i^T\tilde{Z}_j=\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(\tilde{Z}_j\tilde{Z}_i^T)$.

Now let $L$ be any matrix satisfying $LL^T=S$: e.g., a lower triangular Cholesky factor, or the symmetric square root. Define $Z = L\tilde{Z}$.
$$\mathbf{E}(Z_iZ_i^T)=\mathbf{E}(L\tilde{Z}_i\tilde{Z}_i^TL^T)=L\mathbf{E}(\tilde{Z}_i\tilde{Z}_i^T)L^T=LL^T=S\quad\Longrightarrow\quad Z_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,S).$$
$$\mathbf{E}(Z^TS^{-1}Z)=\mathbf{E}(\tilde{Z}^TL^T(LL^T)^{-1}L\tilde{Z})=\mathbf{E}(\tilde{Z}^TL^TL^{-T}L^{-1}L\tilde{Z})=\mathbf{E}(\tilde{Z}^T\tilde{Z})=nI.$$
We get $nI$, not $mI$ as requested above. I can't help but think this is what is intended.

So in summary: you can construct instances $Z$ satisfying the distribution conditions by multiplying a matrix with i.i.d. elements by a square root of $S$.

Comment: could we consider in this case the expected value as one realization because somehow it's the mean of all the realizations?
Actually I tried to generate the above model but in all my trials I don't get $\hat{Z}^TS^{−1}\hat{Z}=mI$ or something similar where $\hat{Z}$ is one realization of the random variable $Z=L\tilde{Z}$.
However I found $\mathrm{trace}(\hat{Z}^TS^{−1}\hat{Z})=\mathrm{trace}(mI)$.
Ultimately, I'm interested in finding a way to force one realization such that $\hat{Z}^TS^{−1}\hat{Z}=mI$ or at least to be similar to $mI$, i.e same trace **and** determinant.

Comment: Then you are not asking for a random variable, you are solving a linear system. There is exactly one answer for that, and it is $\hat{Z}=mL$.